# Reconstructing image using eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab, svd, image-processing

I have 10 images each of $92*92$ dimension. I am also given an eigenvector matrix ($8464*8464$) in the image space of the 10 images.Now I have to convert the basis to images. The bases are same as the set of eigenvectors given. I am not quite sure how to proceed but one possible direction is to find eigenvectors of individual images from the eigenvector matrix. How can I do that?
Can someone nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: See the video of nathan kutz on svd and pca on youtube and you get all clear understanding of eigenvector image projection.

Comment: 92 times 92 is 8464 so it is likely that the eigenvectors are stored in some **vectorization** of the images, but unless you can figure out which vectorization is used, it will be difficult to say how to interpret them as images.

Comment: can u explain a bit more about this vectorization of images?

Comment: vectorization is the process of storing something with more dimensions than one into a one dimensional vector. to be able to turn the vector back into the original dimensions data we need to know in which order the data points were stored in the vector.